# How to approach this fade transition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am building an app using Android Studio, and I cannot figure out how to approach this issue I am facing.

I have a recyclerview that takes up about two-thirds of the lower half of the screen. Above it are three other elements. I need those elements to disappear when the recyclerview gets scrolled, and I need the recyclerview to scale up to fill the entire screen. I have found ways to do this, but they all cause the items inside of the recyclerview to scale up as well, distorting them.

Comment: Use Collapsingtoolbarlayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this implementation:-

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onHide()
        {

            tabss.animate().translationY(tabss.getHeight())
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();      
           filtershow.animate().translationY(-filtershow.getHeight())
                  .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1));
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow()
        {
            tabss.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new
                    DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
         filtershow.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator
                 (new DecelerateInterpolator(1)).start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This solution works incredibly well for animating the things I want to be moved away. Thank you! How can I animate the scale change of the recyclerview though? I need it to scale up to full screen size.

Comment: Try to have the  other elements at the top to be like a toolbar and when scrolled up then perform the smoot toolbar animation

Comment: I ended up solving this by making the recyclerview larger than the screen, and then applying the same animation to it.